# ROS over Ad-Hoc

Tags: ros, multiple, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to run ros on my local network. (2 machines communicating each other) However, sometimes tf lookuptransform gives me timeout errors. I've read that it is caused of time asynchronization between machines. I tried to synchronize them by using NTP but no luck.. I thought maybe if i don't use my router and connect those machines directly over ad-hoc, i can get better results?
Is ad-hoc can be used with ROS? is there any different instructions do i have to follow besides http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153011/ros-over-ad-hoc/) by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Changing the approach for connecting the two machines will not improve time synchronization automatically. NTP already estimates the latency between computers when performing synchronization (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm)). It´s likely that either time synchronization does not work for some reason (then it will likely not work better using ad-hoc networking), or it works and you get tf lookup errors because you transmit too much data over your wireless link, meaning that some tf data gets dropped.

You can check your time sync  as decribed [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup). If it´s good (a few milliseconds max) then your problem likely is not time synchronization and you should look at decreasing the amount of data you transmit between computers. If it´s bad, it´s recommended to install chrony to perform time sync.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-14**:
ok than i will try again by using chrony. I have one more question. In my network i have my laptop and a pandaboard connected over wifi and doing SLAM. Pandaboard supplies base_footprint -> base_stabilized, base_stabilized -> base_link and base_link -> laser frames.

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-14**:
My laptop does SLAM and  generates map -> base_footprint frame. However, when i type rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link on my pandaboard. It cannot find map frame, but when i run tf_echo on my laptop, it shows tf data. Why my pandaboard doesn't get map frame ?

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-14**:
do you think is it related to time sync. or how can i debug the problem? thanks

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-14**:
Could also be related to a network setup issue. You should try if communication works in both direction by running the talker/listener example you posted in your original question.

**Comment by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on 2014-04-14**:
After setting up a network, is there any chance that it works in one direction ?? one of the machines runs roscore, the other one can connect to that roscore and see its rostopic list. Is there any chance that master(the one running roscore) cannot see its clients ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-04-14**:
Yes, IIRC there are (bad) configurations where you can see topics, but not receive data from them. For that reason, you should try out communication in both directions.